# List of lists with tuples to list of lists

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of lists that looks like the following:

```
a = [['he', 'goes'],
     ['he does'],
     ['one time'],
     [('he','is'), ('she', 'went'), ('they', 'are')],
     ['he', 'must'],
     ['they use']]
```

I trying to to flatten the list so that it is only a list of lists with no tuples. For example:

```
a = [['he', 'goes'],
     ['he does'],
     ['one time'],
     ['he','is'], 
     ['she', 'went'],
     ['they', 'are'],
     ['he', 'must'],
     ['they use']]
```

I have tried using `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` however that flattens all of the nested lists.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
b = []
for x in a:
    if isinstance(x[0], tuple):
        b.extend([list(y) for y in x])
    else:
        b.append(x)
```

Comment: Yeah, one of those cases where a loop is clearer. Could also do `list(map(list, x))`, btw. Not sure if better.

Answer (score 6):

Using yield from and python3:

```
from collections import Iterable
def conv(l):
    for ele in l:
        if isinstance(ele[0], Iterable) and not isinstance(ele[0],str):
            yield from map(list,ele)
        else:
            yield ele

print(list(conv(a)))
[['he', 'goes'], ['he does'], ['one time'], ['he', 'is'], ['she', 'went'], ['they', 'are'], ['he', 'must'], ['they use']]
```

For `python2`  you can iterate over an itertools.imap object:

```
from collections import Iterable
from itertools import imap

def conv(l):
    for ele in l:
        if isinstance(ele[0], Iterable) and not isinstance(ele[0],basestring):
            for sub in imap(list, ele):
                yield sub
        else:
            yield ele

print(list(conv(a)))
```

If you have nested tuples you will need to add more logic.

Comment: I tried changing "python to" to "python2" but wasn't allowed because it's too small... (and I don't dare to change more).

Answer (score 5):

This solves your example:

```
a = [list(strings) for sublist in a for strings in
     ([sublist] if isinstance(sublist[0], str) else sublist)]
```

For each sublist that's already a list of strings, just use that sublist. Otherwise iterate through that sublist.

Is that enough or is your actual data more complex?

Comment: Good solution. You could also make it `[list(c) for b in …]` to make sure that the tuples are converted to a list.

Comment: I did not downvote, but, this is extremely hard to read. Maybe using variables with more than just one letter would  make the answer more userfriendly - or an explanation.

Comment: @BeowulfOF Is it ok now?

Comment: Way better, at least for me!

Comment: The most clever answer by far :) Turning lists of strings into lists of lists of strings, so that every element of the big list can be treated as an iterable of iterables of strings.

Comment: @Shashank You know, if I hadn't written the code, the description might confuse me :-P